# What are some current research areas of interest in machine learning and causal inference?

Tags: machine-learning, references, causality

I am wondering if anyone has any references or material that relates to a survey or summary of current topics of research either in machine learning or at the intersection of machine learning and causal inference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Susan Athey and Guido Imbens have kindly put their lecture notes for the various 2018 causal ML courses they have taught on [a public Google Drive folder](https://drive.google.com/drive/mobile/folders/1SEEOMluxBcSAb_tsDYgcLFtOQaeWtkLp?usp=drive_open).

Answer (score 1):

A nice review of some algorithms, with linked papers and packages, here: https://causalml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/about.html

This is only a small subset of the broader research field, but still useful.
For more general reviews see also:

- [Machine learning: An applied econometric approach](https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/jep.31.2.87)
- [ICML Causal Inference tutorial](https://shalit.net.technion.ac.il/homepage/causal-inference-tutorial-icml-2016/)